# SSRS using a SQL stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2008

I have a stored procedure that retrieves data from a linked server.  I can run the stored procedure by setting the single variable.  The results end up in a table in my SQL 2008 R2 database.  The dataset in SSRS calls this stored procedure using the EXEC dbo.ImagePlaceholder @Name command.  Here is the stored procedure:

```
     USE [LagoReporting]


GO
 /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ImagePlaceholder]    Script Date: 03/27/2013 14:22:21    ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:Tim Vavra
-- Create date: 3/27/13
-- Description: Stored procedure to create the table necessary to produce a report that shows all images that are listed
-- as placeholders in Lago.  Included in table will be any job which has a street date greater than today - 30.
-- =============================================


ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ImagePlaceholder]
(
@Name varchar(80)
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET FMTONLY OFF; 


declare @SQL nvarchar(4000)
declare @KATBEZC varchar(80)

drop table dbo.ImagePH

set @KATBEZC = @Name    

Create Table #ActiveTemp(
    media nvarchar(max),
    div nvarchar(max),
    folio nvarchar(max),
    pgblock nvarchar(max),
    item nvarchar(max),
    itemname nvarchar(max),
    photoinstruction nvarchar(max),
    photodirection nvarchar(max),
    PH nvarchar(100),
    imagename nvarchar(max))

Create Table [dbo].[ImagePH](
    media nvarchar(max),
    div nvarchar(max),
    folio nvarchar(max),
    pgblock nvarchar(max),
    item nvarchar(max),
    itemname nvarchar(max),
    photoinstruction nvarchar(max),
    photodirection nvarchar(max),
    PH nvarchar(100),
    imagename nvarchar(max))

      set @SQL=
      N'insert into #ActiveTemp 
      select media, div,folio,pgblock,item, itemname, photoinstruction, photodirection,PH,imagename
      from  OPENQUERY(LAGO,
      ''SELECT DISTINCT KATBEZC media,
art.artvf1c div,
CONCAT(pagprec,pagpags) folio,
pro.probezc pgblock,
art.artvf2c item,
art.artbezc itemname,
art.artvf7c photoinstruction,
art.artvf6c photodirection,
bld.bldtmps PH,
bld.bldfnmc ImageName
FROM dok,
pro,
art,
aez,
kat,
PAG,
kav,
kom,
bld,
boz
WHERE kavkatkeyi = katkeyi
AND artkavkeyi = kavkeyi
AND aezartkeyi = artkeyi
AND aezkavkeyi = artkavkeyi
AND prokeyi = aezprokeyi
AND prokavkeyi = aezkavkeyi
AND komprokeyi = prokeyi
AND (komkavkeyi = 0 OR komkavkeyi = prokavkeyi)
AND dokkeyi = komdokkeyi
AND (prosnei = doksnli OR prosnei = doksnei)
AND dokkeyi = pagdokkeyi
AND PAGPAVKEYI = KATPAVKEYI
and bldtmps = 1
and bozbldkeyi = bldkeyi
and bozobjkeyi = artkeyi
and katbezc = ''''' + @Name + '''''
and boztyps = 2
Group by kat.katbezc,
CONCAT(pagprec,pagpags),
art.artvf1c,
pro.probezc,
art.artvf2c,
art.artbezc,
kom.kombezc,
art.artvf7c,
art.artvf6c,
bld.bldtmps,
bld.bldfnmc
'')'

    exec (@SQL)

    insert into dbo.ImagePH 
    select * from #ActiveTemp

END
```

I am not getting the data back to the report although when I query the database dbo.ImagePH has all of the correct information.

Thanks in advance for any help.  Sorry about the code format.

Comment: every time the report runs, you want to Create Table [dbo].[ImagePH]?  FYI, you can't change data in SSRS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end of your sp is an insert query

```
insert into dbo.ImagePH 
select * from #ActiveTemp
```

If you want it to return results its would need to be a select query

Also

- You should use `sp_executesql` so you execute your query as a parameterized query.
- You shouldn't be using dynamic sql here at any rate
- It makes no sense to populate a temp table. Just insert into dbo.ImagePH directly.

Comment: Conrad - Thanks so much for the help.  I am going to clean some things up going forward including inserting directly into ImagePH table rather than inserting into a temp table first.  If I do that do I still drop the table or should I just delete the records?

Comment: Well as @DanAndrews points out why are you creating ImagePH to begin with? You could just Select the records and then you don't even have to insert into it. However if you're going to do `DELETE * ImagePH` vs `DROP table ImagePH` then you should probably consider `TRUNCATE` instead of delete. [For more see](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7677/196)

Comment: I edited the procedure and eliminated the ImagePH table and just used the temp table.  It is faster and cleaner.  Thanks for all your help.